# how to parse a string to HTML with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, parsing

My string looks like this:

```
<table>
 <tbody>
   <tr>
     <td>Sack</td>
     <td>&nbsp;</td>
     <td>7.48</td>
     <td>&nbsp;</td> 
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Palette</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>23.41</td>
      <td>&nbsp;€</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

I would like to parse it with jquery, so I can add a `<td>` inside of the `<tr>`'s at the end.

I tried the following so far:
Consider that "item[index].preis" containing the String without id or class.

```
var el = $.parseHTML(item[index].preis);
    console.log(el[1]);
```

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

I tried to access to the tr with `.children()` but it didnt work.

Comment: Use `el.find('tr')`, as `tr` are children of `tbody` not the `table` itself

Comment: it says find is not a function

Comment: So you want to just add more table data into the last table row you have?

Comment: @moody `$(el).find('tr')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to insert the same values at the end of each Table Row you can use the following:

```js
var rows = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");

for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++)
{
  var rowToInsert = rows[i];
  var insertPoint = rowToInsert.insertCell(-1);
  insertPoint.innerHTML = "New Value";
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Sack</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>7.48</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Palette</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>23.41</td>
      <td>&nbsp;€</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like that. Just wrap your elements in jQuery Object to perform jQuery Operations on them.

```
var tableStr = "<table><tbody><tr><td>Sack</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>7.48</td><td>&nbsp;</td> </tr><tr><td>Palette</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>23.41</td><td>&nbsp;€</td> </tr></tbody></table>";

  var el = $.parseHTML(tableStr);

  var allRow = $(el).find('tr');
  var allCol = $(allRow).children();
  console.log('all Row');
  console.log(allRow);
  console.log('all Col');
  console.log(allCol);
```

You can also check the fiddle here

`http://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/3156/`

Answer (score 0):

**You can use 'find' to search tr element and then 'append' to append content.**

Do it like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/s9y6qpmv/

```
var elem = "<table><tbody><tr><td>Sack</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>7.48</td><td>&nbsp;</td> </tr><tr><td>Palette</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>23.41</td><td>&nbsp;€</td> </tr></tbody></table>";

var el = $.parseHTML(elem);
    $(el).find("tr").append("<td>Game</td>")
    console.log($(el).html());

    $("body").append(el);
```